# Custom CKEditor in Angular 13 - Error Message: "Property 'create' is missing in type '{ ClassicEditor: {}; }' but required in type 'EditorConstructor'

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I am trying to use a CKEditor5 Custom Build into my angular project, however, I'm getting a weird error that I cannot solve. I created an empty project and added ckeditor-custom-build directory in the root: next to src & node_modules.

I have followed the tutorials: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/angular.html#using-a-custom-ckeditor-5-build

Environment:

- @angular/common: 13.1.0
- @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular: 4.0.0
- @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic: 34.2.0

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CKEditorModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.js

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Editor from 'ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ckeditor-test';
  public editor = Editor;

  config: any = {
    toolbar: ['heading', 'bold', 'italic'],
    language: 'en'
  };
  html: string = '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
  constructor() {}
}
```

app.component.html

```
      <ckeditor [editor]="editor" 
                [(ngModel)]="html"
      ></ckeditor>
```

Error Message in Console

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:332:18 - error TS2741: Property 'create' is missing in type '{ ClassicEditor: {}; }' but required in type 'EditorConstructor'.

332       <ckeditor [editor]="editor"
                     ~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Comment: Can you try this import of Editor instead ? 
`import * as Editor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';`

Comment: It does work with that import, I'm trying to import a custom build in my project.

Answer (score 2):

in component.ts file while initializing the custom editor include type as any

```
  public editor: any = Editor;
```

Comment: Works for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with **ckeditor5** in the past with no problems.

I can see you are using the following import

```
import * as Editor from 'ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';
```

In my case it was this import

```
import * as Editor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';
```

I'll share my config which is supposed to remain the same.

Now first thing is that since **ckeditor5** doesn't contain typings, and **Angular** would complain about it, I had to create the following file: **`editor-typings.d.ts`**

```
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document' {
  const Editor: any;
  export = Editor;
}
```

Now in your `app.component.ts` add the following method

```
init(editor: any): void {
  editor.ui
    .getEditableElement()
    .parentElement.insertBefore(
      editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
      editor.ui.getEditableElement()
    );
}
```

In your `app.component.html`, you need to bind this method with your **ckeditor5** `ready`'s output event like this

```
<ckeditor [editor]="editor" (ready)="init($event)"></ckeditor>
```

Let me know if the problem would still be there.

Comment: I'm using a CKEditor5 custom build. I configured the build on https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/. Downloaded the build and move the files to the ckeditor5 folder that sits on the root directory and downloaded npm dependencies there.  Then, I imported the editor instance from 'ckeditor5/build/ckeditor'

Comment: Not Working with Angular 14